# How do I update specific field in Firebase with Push IDs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the **status** to "complete" once the user selects one of the options. I am not sure how to read the particular field because of the auto generated push ids. Screenshot of firebase database attached

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6EVF.png)

Comment: Queries are covered in the Firebase [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data). Also, Please do NOT include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the `uid` of the node you `.push` then ask the ref for the `.key` like below. To update, you `.update`.

> ```
> // Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
> var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
>   author: "gracehop",
>   title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
> });
> // Get the unique ID generated by push() by accessing its key
> var postID = newPostRef.key;
> ```